# How to avoid warning when using scope guard?

Tags: c++, c++11, scopeguard, folly

I am using folly  scope guard, it is working, but it generates a warning saying that the variable is unused:

```
warning: unused variable ‘g’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

The code:

```
folly::ScopeGuard g = folly::makeGuard([&] {close(sock);});
```

How to avoid such warning?

Comment: I think you are not supposed to use `folly::ScopeGuard g = folly::makeGuard([&] {close(sock);});`. You are supposed to use `SCOPE_EXIT{close(sock);}`. See if that makes the warning go away. If it doesn't, there is probably a way to hack a use into the definition.

Comment: What compiler version? If `g`'s destructor actually does something then the compiler should not be warning about this , it could be considered a bug (and may have been fixed in later versions).

Comment: It should be noted that C++17 seems to be getting a `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute that would provide a standard-guaranteed way of declaring that a variable will be unusued.

Comment: @M.M: It is not unreasonable for compilers to warn about such variables, even if they have destructors that do things. If you just declare a `std::string` and accidentally forget to use it, the compiler still ought to warn about it, since you almost certainly meant to do something with it.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair point

Comment: @M.M, I am using gcc 5.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this warnings by `-Wno-unused-variable`, though this is a bit dangerous (you loose all *realy unused* variables).

One possible solution is to actually *use* the variable, but do nothing with it. For example, case it to void:

```
(void) g;
```

which can be made into a macro:

```
#define IGNORE_UNUSED(x) (void) x;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [boost aproach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/ignore_unused.html): declare a templated function that does nothing and use it

```
template <typename T>
void ignore_unused (T const &) { }

...

folly::ScopeGuard g = folly::makeGuard([&] {close(sock);});
ignore_unused(g);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just label the variable as being unused:

```
folly::ScopeGuard g [[gnu::unused]] = folly::makeGuard([&] {close(sock);});
```

Or cast it to void:

```
folly::ScopeGuard g = folly::makeGuard([&] {close(sock);});
(void)g;
```

Neither is great, imo, but at least this lets you keep the warnings.